# Extraction permitted peer cert details in ruleset

Tags: rsyslog

We are using imtcp with gtls and specifies the permitter cert subjects in PermittedPeer. This works well, but we would like to extract the cert subject and include in the log message we send further with omkafka.

Are there some hidden variables that contains any cert details?

Use it like this (non working example:-) :

```
module( load="imtcp" StreamDriver.Name="gtls" StreamDriver.AuthMode="x509/name"  StreamDriver.Mode="1" PermittedPeer=[ "cert-subject-we-allow" ] )
input( type="imtcp" port="12345" name="name" ruleset="name" )

ruleset(name="name") {
  set $!meta!cert!subject = $.hidden!cert!info??...
}
```

Environment:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
- syslog-8.24.0-34.el7.x86_64
- rsyslog-mmjsonparse-8.24.0-34.el7.x86_64
- rsyslog-kafka-8.24.0-34.el7.x86_64
- rsyslog-gnutls-8.24.0-34.el7.x86_64